# Configure webapi in Windows Forms to accept CROS

Tags: c#, jquery, json, cross-browser, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing a project for college where one WebSite sends commands to a Windows Forms application. This application is Responsible for access to serial port and send and receive commands.

Communication between the website and the Windows Forms application, I used Web Api. I need to setup webapi Implementing CORS, but all examples I've seen are for MVC and I need for Windows Forms. I placed the order that I'm calling from the client and how webapi in my Windows Forms is configured.

Also, put the error that Chrome returns me.

Class WebApi with Windows Forms

```
public class GPSController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Coordenada Posicao()
    {
        return TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.PegarCoordenadas();
    }
}
```

Configuration WebApi Windows Forms

```
private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button2.Text == "Iniciar serviço")
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(textBox1.Text);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });


        server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        server.OpenAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Serviço inicializado!");
        button2.Text = "Parar serviço";
    }
    else
    {
        server.CloseAsync();
        button2.Text = "Iniciar serviço";
    }
}
```

Get WebApi Jquery my MVC Site

```
function cmdLocal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:8089/api/gps/",
        success: function(callback){
           alert(callback);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert("You have a error"+err);
        }
    });         
}
```

Error Get cmdLocal, with Chrome

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8089/api/gps/. Origin http://localhost:36452 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How to implement CORS in a Windows Forms application?

tks

Answer (score 0):

If the CORS support is implemented as a DelegatingHandler then there should be no difference between how it is used with Web Host versus self host.
The only problem will come is if the CORS implementation is dependent on `HttpContext`.

What CORS implementation are you trying to use?

BTW your windows form app will need to run as admin for what you trying to do to work.

Comment: I did not find any practical example to put in Windows Forms, this is what I need. Would have an example?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt The Thinktecture Identity model one should work just fine http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Just pass your config to corsConfig.RegisterGlobal(config);

Comment: its Thinktecture support Windows Forms?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt This has absolutely nothing to do with Windows Forms.  You are creating a self-host Web API server.  This could be a console app, a WPF app, a WinForms app, a Windows Service, it would work in exactly the same way.